# How to minimize $\frac{x}{N} \cdot[ (\frac{x}{x+1})^{(N-x)} - 1]$

Tags: functions, optimization

Let $N\gg0$, I'm looking to minimize the following expression:
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{N} \cdot[ (\frac{x}{x+1})^{(N-x)} - 1]$$

Where $0\le x\le N$.

In particular, I'm wondering whether $\forall x:f(x)> - \frac{1}{e}$.

---

If this is not clear, a bound would be more than enough. I'm aware this has a minimum, and I conjecture that $f(x)> - \frac{1}{e}$, but can't seem to complete the math.

Comment: @Servaes- Yes, unfortunately, this does not seems tractable (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+x%2FN+*+%28%28x+%2F+%28x%2B1%29%29+%5E+%28N-x%29+-+1%29).

Comment: Sidenote: $N\gg 0$ doesn't make much sense - any positive $N$ will do. You probably mean $N\gg 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(0)=f(N)=0$ and [the minimum is achieved for $x\gg 1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2F1000%29%28%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%281000-x%29-1%29+for+x+from+0+to+1000). In that region approximate $$\frac x{x+1}\approx e^{-1/x}$$
and make subsitution $\alpha=x/n\in[\epsilon,1]$ to get
$$f(x)\approx g(\alpha)=\alpha(e^{1-1/\alpha}-1)$$
W|A also says [$\min_{\alpha\in[0,1]} g(\alpha)\approx -0.3178>-e^{-1}\approx -0.3678$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+x%28e%5E%281-1%2Fx%29-1%29+for+x%3D0+to+1). This approximation can be massaged into a proper lower bound as there is plenty of wiggle room.